# Xargs doesn't listen to stdin

Tags: linux, bash, xargs, ubuntu

I try to add an svn:keywords property to all existing *.php and *.phtml files. Therefore, I use this command:

```
find . -regex '.*\.php' -o -regex '.*\.phtml'|xargs svn propset svn:keywords "Id"
```

This should, according to [Mateusz Loskot](http://mateusz.loskot.net/2007/11/16/bulk-svnkeywords-property-update/), add the property to all files. If I run `find . -regex '.*\.php' -o -regex '.*\.phtml'`, all files are found but xargs returns this message: `xargs: svn: No such file or directory`.

I also tried to export the found list (`>> ~/temp`) and use `xargs -a` to read the arguments from a file input, without success. How can I update all my php files?

PS. I use Kubuntu Linux Natty (11.04), which has built in bash 4.2.8 and xargs 4.4.2 (if that might matter)

Comment: "svn: No such file or directory" sounds like you haven't installed Subversion. What does `svn --version` return?

Comment: apart from l0b0's solution, this is a question for http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Aarg! I had kdesvn installed and that worked really well. I thought kdesvn would have a dependency on svn, which is not and therefore subversion was not installed. So it's now and xargs works fine! Thanks l0b0 :s

Comment: @Jurian Sluiman: If the error message is telling you it can't find 'svn', why do you thinkthee problem is that xargs can't do exactly what it was designed to do? First rule of debugging: assume the error message is telling the truth.

Comment: @Bryan: `xargs` uses files as input argument (the list generated by `find`) so when a *file* is not found, I connect this file not found error to the file list given as argument. So I don't judge the error message, I just try to convert it into a possible cause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your command looks ok. It seems that `xargs` cannot find `svn` command in `PATH`. Verify that it is available or use full file path (`which svn` should display full path to `svn`).

To prevent *spaces in file name issue* I would recommend `-print0` argument for `find` and `-0` for `xargs`:

```
find . -name '\*.php' -o -name '\*.phtml' -print0 | xargs -0 svn propset svn:keywords "Id"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the usual tricks here, such as:

```
find ... | while read i ; do svn propset svn:keywords Id "$i" ; done
```

Comment: In this specific case you'll get the same error. While your solution might work for some, it is not useful to solve _this_ question. Plus, xargs is exactly the right command in this situation. Suggesting to use while/read arguably makes the code worse rather than better.

Comment: I disagree. It could be a solution *if* the problem has to do with file names with spaces, not handled correctly in the question.